# MS Access 2010 ListBox items not selectable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am populating a listbox on an MS Access 2010 form with results from a stored procedure. The code I am using to populate the listbox is as follows:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PassThroughQuery")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC Search '" & searchValue & "'"
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset

While Not rs.EOF
    Me.searchResultsBox.AddItem rs("name")
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

The query runs fine and the ListBox populates with the specified values, however the items in the list box are not selectable. I cannot click and highlight any of the items.

I checked the Enabled and Locked properties and they are set to True and False respectively. The "Row Source Type" is set to "Value List". I'm at a loss as to why the listbox values are behaving as the are.

Comment: Just grasping at straws: What are the Control Source and Bound Column properties?  Do you have procedure code or macro attached to the combo's click or other events?  What's up with `dbCmd` ... is it relevant here?

Comment: @HansUp Sorry, the dbCmd is not relevant ... it's old code that I forgot to take out, my bad there. The Control Source property is empty and the Bound Column is 1. I've tried blanking out the Bound Column but it's apparently a required field and Access Complains about it if it's left blank.

Comment: OK, this one seems odd to me, which makes me wonder about corruption.  You could try `Application.SaveAsText acForm, "FormName",      "C:\SomeFolder\FormName.txt"`  Then in a new db file `Application.LoadFromText acForm, "FormName", "C:\SomeFolder\FormName.txt"` and see if the new one shows the same symptom.  Naturally you'd also have to import any tables and such the form depends.  But honestly I don't know whether this suggestion will be any more useful than my first comment.  :-(

Comment: @HansUp I'll definitely have to give that a try! I appreciate your help! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem: apparently listbox items are only selectable when editing is allowed. Maybe the forms `Allow Edits` property is set to false. It may also be that results from a pass through query or a stored procedure are not editable.

Comment: Thank you! For me that was it: I had to set the `Allow Edits` property (in the *Data* tab) of the containing form to `Yes`. Oh, how I love Access...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget allow edits at the form level as well even if you want everything read only.  For me the listbox was only selectable when I set both to allow edits.